# I want to use when on pyspark dataframe but i have multiple columns df.withcolumn

Tags: python, pyspark, conditional-statements

Dataframe Schema:

root |--LAST_UPDATE_DATE |--ADDR_1 |--ADDR_2 |--ERROR

If the "ERROR" col is null i want to change df like :

```
df = df.withColumn("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", current_timestamp()) \
   .withColumn("ADDR_1", lit("ADDR_1")) \
   .withColumn("ADDR_2", lit("ADDR_2"))
```

else :

```
df = df.withColumn("ADDR_1", lit("0"))
```

i have checked the "when-otherwise" but only one column can be changed in that scenario

Desired output :

```
//+----------------+------+------+-----+
//|LAST_UPDATE_DATE|ADDR_1|ADDR_2|ERROR|
//+----------------+------+------+-----+
//|2022-06-17 07:54|ADDR_1|ADDR_2| null| 
//|            null|  null|  null|    1|
//+----------------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Could you also add an example of desired output?

Comment: @AlaTarighati have made the changes

Comment: Does it satisfy you `else` statement?

Comment: yes i have kept one row for the if part and one for the else path, displaying both scenarios @AlaTarighati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use when-otherwise for each witnColumn? Condition can be taken out for convenience.
Example:

```
error_event = F.col('ERROR').isNull()

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('LAST_UPDATE_DATE', F.when(error_event, F.current_timestamp()))
    .withColumn('ADDR_1', F.when(error_event, F.lit('ADDR_1'))
                          .otherwise(1))
)
```

Comment: I need to perform the same activity with a few other columns as well, it would look redundant

Comment: if the action is the same type, you can use cycles